# RESTFul pattern url for enable and disable

Tags: rest, url, design-patterns

What's the RESTFul pattern for *enabling* and *disabling* a system user.

Example:
a `DELETE` request to  `/users/123` 
and  `PATCH/UPDATE` request to `/users/123`

Or should I use `/user/enable/123` using `PUT` and `/user/disable/123` using `DELETE`?

Comment: `REST` is neither a protocol nor does it prescribe how you have to design your API, it is simply a system design architecture to decouple clients from servers/APIs. URI design is not of much interest to an actual REST client as it just will use a URI returned by the service to invoke such without interpreting what the semantics of that URI might be

Comment: In practice, there are usually two ways to go. Either ([1](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#enable-a-workflow)) `PUT /user/123/enable` + `DELETE /user/123/enable`, or ([2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurespringapps/services/enable-test-endpoint?tabs=HTTP)) `POST /user/123/enable` + `POST /user/123/disable`

Answer (score 11):

First of all: `DELETE` always removes a resource. So it **cannot** be used to change a value. Read more about the different Http methods and how they are supposed to used here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

You can solve this in three different ways. Whatever fits you best.

**Update user object**

Another approach would be by updating the `User` resource.
In this case you could send a  `PUT /users/123` with a body that contains the full updated user object.

**Partial update of user object**

If you define that you are allowed to do partial updates (partial means you only need to send the changed values which will be merged in to the existing user object) you can send a `PATCH /users/123` containing a json with `{enabled:true}`. This is usually a bit trickier to handle on the backend.

**Directly set enabled property** (not recommended)

`enabled` is a property of a `User`. There for you can address this property directly in your URL.
You can use `PUT /users/123/enabled` with a body that contains `true` or `false`. To this approach, also see @Roman Vottner comment below

Comment: First, exposing the `enabled` property as own subresource is a workaround to make the available toolset fit the problem more nicely though it is questionable if this sub-resource on its own should be considered a sub-resource in first place. One might argue that the "overlapping resources" note in RFC7231 exactly describes this, though on the other hand in terms of resources it feels more like a hack TBH. For the partial update I'd use [JsonPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/) as a patch request should contain instructions the server has to execute either fully or not at all

Comment: If 'disabling' a user semantically means that your user would be removed, you can use user DELETE.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the RESTFul pattern for enabling and disabling a system user.

How would you do it with pages on a web site?

It might be that you would load a page that describes the system user, and from there navigate to a form with affordances for changing the users state; you would set the values on the form you want, and submit the form to the URL provided.  The server would process the request, and either give you a status page, or redirect you back to an updated copy of the user, or whatever.

Notice: throughout the entire process, the client is *following* links provided by the server; no guessing URI, no guessing which http methods to use; the client follows the instructions embedded in the hypermedia

Repeat that same process in a machine readable way, and you've got a REST api.

REST, keep in mind, is about manipulating "resources" by passing messages around; the changes made to your domain model are *side effects* of the resource manipulation.  In other words, the resources are part of your integration domain.  See Jim Webber - [REST: DDD in the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc)